# Converting nonlinear program into linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following *nonlinear* optimization problem
\begin{align}
\min \quad c^Tx &+ f(d^Tx)\\
\text{s.t.} \quad Ax &\geq b\\
x &\geq 0
\end{align}

where
$$
f(y) =
\begin{cases}
-y+2 \quad &\text{if}\quad y\leq2\\
0 \quad &\text{if}\quad 2\lt y\leq 4\\
\frac{1}{2}y-2 &\text{if}\quad y\gt 4
\end{cases}
$$

and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and $c,d\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are given.

(a) Carefully sketch the function $f(y)$. (done)

(b) Reformulate the optimization problem as an equivalent Linear Program. (done)

(c) Write your Linear Program in the form 
\begin{align}
\min \quad a^T w &\\
\text{s.t.}\quad Bw &\geq g\\
w &\geq 0
\end{align}

providing the relevant definitions of $a$, $w$, $B$ and $g$.

I've already reformulated the optimization problem as:
\begin{align}
\min\quad c^Tx + z& \\
\text{s.t.}\qquad Ax &\geq b\\
d^Tx+z &\geq 2\\
-\frac{1}{2}d^Tx + z &\geq -2\\
x &\geq 0\\
z &\geq 0
\end{align}

where $z \equiv \max(-y+2, 0, \frac{1}{2}y-2)$. I'm not quite sure how to start part c. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think your answer on (b) is not correct. Think about the following. In your linear problem: Is $z$ a unknown or a parameter? What is $y$ (on which $z$ depends)?

Comment: @gerw I edited it. Not entirely sure why I had constants instead of z in the reformulated LP. Must be getting late.

Comment: Now simply define $w = (x,z)$ and write everything in a matrix format. Note, $z$ is not equal to the max function as you write. It is intended to act as an upper bound of that function, but at optimality, equality will hold (as z would be sub-optimal otherwise)

Comment: @JohanLöfberg: This could serve as an answer.